# Create a fixed length string function (originally from Java)

Tags: ios, swift, string

I'm trying to create a fixed length string function in swift.  I know how it's done in Java for Android but unsure how to translate it to Swift.  This is what the Java function looks like:

```
private String getFixedLengthString(String name, int fixedLength) {
    if(name == null) {
        name = "";
    }
    if(name.length() > fixedLength) {
        name = name.substring(0, fixedLength);
    }
    return String.format("%1$-" + fixedLength + "s", name);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but you are in the wrong place. SO it is not a code conversion website. You should show what you have tried and the issues you are facing. You should take a moment and read hot to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read [Swift Strings documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) to find what you want

Comment: Moreover, explaining what exactly you are trying to achieve would help a lot in receiving an answer, since in that case, someone without any Java knowledge could also help.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight he is trying to trim not pad

Comment: @DávidPásztor   I'm trying to add a string and a and a fixed length to a function to check if the string is the same as the fixed length, but if the string is nil, return empty space, " ".

Comment: @SwiftyJD Show what you have tried first. Nobody should do your homework for you

Comment: @LeoDabus He tries to do both - his `substring` line trims, while his `return` line pads.

Comment: @SwiftyJD I haven't written Java code for a long time, but if I get your code write, that's not what the Java function does. You want to return a String looking like `"\(input/substring)-\(fixedLength)"`, where input/substring consists of the first `fixedLength` characters of `name`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `prefix` function to get the first `fixedLength` characters of a `String`. The output String format can easily be achieved using String interpolation.

```
func getFixedLengthString(name:String?,fixedLength:Int)->String{
    if let name = name {
        if name.count > fixedLength {
            return "\(name.prefix(fixedLength))-\(fixedLength)s"
        } else {
            return "\(name)-\(fixedLength)s"
        }
    } else {
        return "-\(fixedLength)s"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func getFixedLengthString(_ name: String?, _ fixedLength: Int) -> String{
    var myName = name
    if myName == nil{
        myName = ""
    }

    if myName!.characters.count > fixedLength{
        myName = myName?.substring(to: fixedLength)
    }
    return "\(myName!)-\(fixedLength)s"
    }
```

try this

Comment: substring it is deprecated Swift4

Comment: I did'nt say it didn't work. Anyway you should unwrap your optional instead of checking against nil and forcing unwrap it later

Comment: you can substituate substring with myName = myName[..fixedLength]

Comment: i force unwrapp becouse if it is nil i give an empty string ""

Comment: Just use nil coalescing operator `??` and provide a default value to your string

Comment: yes you are wright, but he is newbie, and he wants it as in android, so i was making something equivalent for him

Comment: @eneadume this is giving a error on the .substring - "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String.Index'"

Comment: @eneadume fixedLength should be a String.Index not an Int. Btw if you would like to subscript String with an Int you can take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613?s=1|43.0600#38215613. It also supports partial range operator