# Least convoluted way of extracting parts of string in Swift 4

Tags: swift, substring, swift4

If I want to extract parts of a string in Swift 4 (when building a Mac app in Xcode 10), are there less convoluted ways of extracting said parts? The code below works, but to me it's nearly unreadable.

```
let myString = "foobar"
let myShorterString = String(myString[myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)..<myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)])
```

I want to end up with `oba` in this case.

Some documentation claims that `"foobar"[2...5]` should work, but to me that throws the error `cannot subscript String with an integer range`. Also, 'substring(to:)' has reportedly been deprecated.

I am aware of [Leo Dabus' thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215613/2450941), but even though that seems prudent, it has approx. 60 lines of code, so I think of that as more convoluted. I'm looking for *less* convoluted answers, and if there are none, confirmation that this is the simplest solution.

**Answer:**

```
let myShorterString = String(Array(myString)[2...4])
```

Courtesy of [Harsh G.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47229985/2450941).

Comment: You should describe what it does also in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215613/2303865

Comment: You really don't need to include the answer to your question in the question itself. In fact, you probably shouldn't. That aside, and aside from this being a duplicate, this was a well-written question. Thank you for putting in the effort to actually ask something good.