# Create a SUBSCRIPT EXTENSION for String with integer Range

Tags: swift, string, range

This solution with two integers works, but I'd like to use a range instead:

```
extension String {
   subscript(start: Int, end: Int) -> String? {
      return String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: start＃)...index(startIndex, offsetBy: end)])
   }
}
```

The two following solutions use ranges, but both produce the same error, not in the extension code, but when attempting to use it:

> 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an integer range.

This is an absurd error that's basically telling me there is no range subscript for String, when in fact I just created it, so it DOES exist.

```
extension String {
   subscript(range: Range<String.IndexDistance>) -> String? {
      return String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.startIndex)...index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.endIndex)])
   }

   subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> String? {
      return String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.startIndex)...index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.endIndex)])
   }
}

let greeting = "Hello, World"
print(greeting[0...4]) // should print "Hello"
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the various answers in https://stackoverflow.com/q/24092884/1187415  (such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215613/1187415) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error is not unexpected. The type of the range `0...4` is not `Range<Int>`, but `ClosedRange<Int>`, which are unrelated types. If you modify your `subscript` implementation to take a `ClosedRange<Int>` instead of a `Range<Int>`, your code compiles and works just fine.

```
extension String {
    subscript(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> String? {
        return String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)...index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)])
    }
}
```

If you want to return `nil` in case any of the indices would produce a range out of bounds exception, you can use `index(_:,offsetBy:,limitedBy:)`.

```
extension String {
    subscript(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> String? {
        guard let startIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound,limitedBy: endIndex), let endIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound,limitedBy: endIndex) else { return nil }
        return String(self[startIndex...endIndex])
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you, David.
How would you add a guard statement that compares range.endIndex to the count of the String to prevent an index-out-of-range error?
The types seem to be incompatible.

Comment: oh... It doesn't quite work.
I'm trying with the following code:

    let numbers = "0123456789"
    numbers[0...4] // correct: "01234"
    numbers[2...2] // incorrect: "234"

Comment: @Hikarus please specify "doesn't quite work". With my test inputs, it works just fine

Comment: sorry, I accidentally pressed enter before the comment was finished. I'm trying with [2...3] or [2], and it doesn't produce a correct result...

Comment: it's ok. I got it in the solution link :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer base on @Dávid Pásztor's code:

```
extension String {
    subscript(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> String? {
        guard let startIdx = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound,limitedBy: endIndex), let endIdx = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound,limitedBy: endIndex) else { return nil }
        return String(self[startIdx...endIdx])
     }   
}
```

---

Here is the where the mistake occurs

```
let startIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound,limitedBy: endIndex)

// startIndex shall be self. startIndex, name does matter
let endIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound,limitedBy: endIndex)
```

Answer (score -1):

Very recommend to use always utf16, when work with strings, to exclude any exceptions:

```
public extension String {
    subscript(range: NSRange) -> String {
        let start = self.utf16.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let end = self.utf16.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)
        return String(self[start..<end])
    }
}
```

Works good, tested, dont get any errors!

Comment: This code fails in many cases. Try it with a string such as `"‍‍"` and a range of `NSRange(location: 2, length: 1)` and see how it gives a totally incorrect result. Many Emoji (and other) characters take far more than a single UTF-16 character.

Comment: So what we need to use, to not get crash?

Comment: The example I gave doesn't crash with your code, it just gives the wrong result. The correct solution is to use the accepted answer above.

Comment: ok, thanks for get in touch for me about this - I'm check it out!