# How to get the First Character in a name

Tags: swift4

I have below func in my class.

```
static func getFirstCharInName(strName: String) -> String {

   let firstCharInName = String(strName.first)

    return firstCharInName.trim()
}
```

I encountered this err:

Value of optional type 'Character?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Character'

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: why not just `let first = String(name[name.startIndex...name.startIndex])`...? – and you might need to check whether the string has at least 1 character for doing some failsafe _(see my answer, I just created eventually)_.

Comment: User can find solution from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language

Answer (score 0):

```
func getFirstCharInName(strName: String) -> String {
    let indexStartOfText = strName.index(strName.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
    let indexEndOfText = strName.index(strName.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
    let firstChar = String(strName[indexStartOfText...indexEndOfText])
    return firstChar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the expression has optional value (the value can be nil) that is not yet unwrapped, `strName.first` returns an optional value of `Character?`, but your function demands a returning type of `String` which is not an optional type.

So, in order to fix this, you need to unwrap the optional value `strName.first`, it seems like you are not familiar with [optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330), here's the code for your case (choose one from two options):

```
func getFirstCharInName(strName: String) -> String {
    // option 1: force unwrap - can cause fatal error
    return String(strName.first!)

    // option 2: optional binding
    if let firstCharInName = strName.first {
        return String(firstCharInName)
    } else {
        // if the optional value is nil, return an empty string
        return ""
    }
}
```

PS. I don't really understand the function `trim()` in your question, but if you mean to strip away the blank spaces like `"  "`, you can do:

```
firstCharInName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that:

```
extension String {

    var firstLetter: String {

        guard !self.isEmpty else { return "" }
        return String(self[self.startIndex...self.startIndex])
    }
}
```

---

then

```
let name = "MilkBottle"
let first = name.firstLetter // "M"
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the optional simply with [`prefix`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix), it's totally safe. if there is no first character you'll get an empty string.

```
static func getFirstChar(in name: String) -> String { // the function name getFirstChar(in name is swiftier
    return String(name.prefix(1))
}
```

I don't know what the `trim` function is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

It means that value of optional type 'Character?' (as result of your part of code strName.first) must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Character' before you  will be gonna cast it to String type.
You may use this variant:

```
func getFirstCharInName(strName: String) -> String {
   return strName.count != 0 ? String(strName.first!) : ""
}
```

As you can see, the exclamation point is in the string **strName.first!** retrieves the optional variable as it was needed.