# How can I gave custom Index to String.Index working with unicode in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

I want gave a custom Index to my code which that means the custom String/Character to read unicodeScalars for that String in that spacial position, for example this down code works with
`string.startIndex` but I could not change it the index that I wanted, even the codes gave error in runtime for `string.endIndex` So I need help, right now this down code works just for index zero of string, for example I want this work for **index = 1** that means **B**, how can I do this?

```
let string: String = "ABC"
let UInt32Value: UInt32 = string.unicodeScalars[string.startIndex].value
print(UInt32Value)
```

---

**Update:** you can replace `string.startIndex` with `customIndex`

```
let index: Int = 1
let customIndex: String.Index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
```

---

**Still need help to know why** `string.endIndex` **not working!?!**

Comment: You index the unicode scalars in the same way as you index the string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613#38215613

Comment: @Sweeper, thanks for help, that was more about working with String length or something like that, but i got what I wanted,

Comment: As for why `string.endIndex` is not working: `string.endIndex` is the index __past the end position__, so if you need the index of the last element of a string, you need `index(endIndex, offsetBy: -1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an extension on `String` where you take the index as either a `String.Index` or an `Int`, then use that to subscript `unicodeScalars`.

```
extension String {
    func unicodeScalarValue(at index: String.Index) -> UInt32 {
        unicodeScalars[index].value
    }
    
    func unicodeScalarValue(at index: Int) -> UInt32 {
        unicodeScalars[self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)].value
    }
}

"ABC".unicodeScalarValue(at: 0)
"ABC".unicodeScalarValue(at: 1)
"ABC".unicodeScalarValue(at: 2)
```