# Swift: Cannot figure out this crash when using safe index Extension to index into an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing

I'm using [this extension](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/say-goodbye-to-index-out-of-range-swift-eca7c4c7b6ca#:%7E:text=One%20common%20error%20every%20array,production%20or%20on%20distributed%20code.) to safely index into an array, which has worked well, but now and then I am seeing a crash on this line `guard let priorSamplesEndDate = currentSamplesInShiftInterval[safe: indexOfCurrentSample - 1]?.endDate else { return }` and cannot figure out how this could ever be out of range?

```
//Safe Indexing Extension
    extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
       public subscript(safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
         return (startIndex <= index && index < endIndex) ? self[index] : nil
       }
    }

//usage
  if currentSamplesInShiftInterval.count > 1 {
            
            guard let indexOfCurrentSample = currentSamplesInShiftInterval.firstIndex(of: distanceSample) else {return }
            guard let priorSamplesEndDate = currentSamplesInShiftInterval[safe: indexOfCurrentSample - 1]?.endDate else { return } //crash occurs here for index out of range

}
```

Comment: Is your array being mutated in another thread concurrently?

Comment: @Paulw11 it is accessed and read outside of the class but is not mutated. 

Comment: Not related to your post but I would use `indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil` instead

Comment: Btw try the implementation I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215613/2303865) it is much safer

Comment: @LeoDabus will do, thank you!