# Convert a given UTF8 NSRange in a string to a UTF16 NSRange

Tags: swift, range, nsrange

Converting any given UTF8 NSRange in a string to a UTF16 NSRange

Examples:

```
let str = #"let  = "hello world""#

//The UTF8 NSRange of  is: {4, 12}
//The UTF16 NSRange of  is: {4, 6}

//The UTF8 NSRange of let  is: {0, 16}
//The UTF16 NSRange of let  is: {0, 10}
```

Testing count:

```
print("".utf8.count) //12
print("".utf16.count) //6

print("let ".utf8.count) //16
print("let ".utf16.count) //10
```

I have only the UTF8 ranges, so what I need is to convert any of them to UTF16 range.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how you would use `index(_:offsetBy:)` to get the nth index when [finding the nth character of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26775912/5133585), you can use the same method here, except on the `UTF8View` of the string.

Find both the start and end indices of the range as `String.Index`, then create a `Range<String.Index>`. Then you can create a `NSRange` from that.

```
let str = #"let  = "hello world""#
let utf8Range = NSRange(location: 4, length: 12)
let startIndex = str.utf8.index(str.utf8.startIndex, offsetBy: utf8Range.lowerBound)
let endIndex = str.utf8.index(startIndex, offsetBy: utf8Range.length)
let stringRange = startIndex..<endIndex
let utf16Range = NSRange(stringRange, in: str)
print(utf16Range)
```